# KineticJS - How to make own event, or how do somthing when the obcjet is moving

Tags: javascript, html, events, kineticjs, collision

I made a simple application in KineticJS. In my app I need to create a few circles, which can be drag and drop and I need to detect collision between them. Now I have 6 bubbles (circle), I can move them and also detect collision using the "dragmove" event. It's works, bubbles run away from the bubble I'm dragging. But I need detect collision between other bubble as well. How i can do this? I don't see "move" event only "mousemove". Any ideas how i can make my own event or other solution?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/TweenLite.min.js"></script>

    <script defer="defer">
      function collide(id, x, y, radius)<!-- moja własne metoda kolizji -->
      {
        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {

            if(bubbleTab[i].getId() != id)
            {
                if(Math.sqrt(((bubbleTab[i].getX()-x)*(bubbleTab[i].getX()-x))+((bubbleTab[i].getY()-y)*(bubbleTab[i].getY()-y))) < (radius+bubbleTab[i].getRadius()))
                    {
                        if(Math.abs(x-bubbleTab[i].getX()) <= radius/2)
                        {
                            <!-- Kierunek góra dół -->
                            if(y>bubbleTab[i].getY())
                            {
                                bubbleTab[i].setY(y-radius-bubbleTab[i].getRadius()-1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bubbleTab[i].setY(y+radius+bubbleTab[i].getRadius()+1);
                            }
                        }
                        else if(Math.abs(y-bubbleTab[i].getY()) <= radius/2)
                        {
                            <!-- Kierunek lewo prawo -->
                            if(x>bubbleTab[i].getX())
                            {
                                bubbleTab[i].setX(x-radius-bubbleTab[i].getRadius()-1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bubbleTab[i].setX(x+radius+bubbleTab[i].getRadius()+1);
                            }
                        }
                        else if(x > bubbleTab[i].getX())
                        {
                            <!-- gora lewo dol lewo -->
                            if(y>bubbleTab[i].getY())
                            {
                                bubbleTab[i].setX(bubbleTab[i].getX()-4);
                                bubbleTab[i].setY(bubbleTab[i].getY()-4);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bubbleTab[i].setX(bubbleTab[i].getX()-4);
                                bubbleTab[i].setY(bubbleTab[i].getY()+4);
                            }                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <!-- gora prawo dol prawo -->
                            if(y>bubbleTab[i].getY())
                            {
                                bubbleTab[i].setX(bubbleTab[i].getX()+4);
                                bubbleTab[i].setY(bubbleTab[i].getY()-4);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bubbleTab[i].setX(bubbleTab[i].getX()+4);
                                bubbleTab[i].setY(bubbleTab[i].getY()+4);
                            }
                        }

                    }
            }
        }
      }

      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 1300,
        height: 500
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var bubbleTab = new Array(6);
      for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
        var bubble = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: (stage.getWidth() / 2)-80+(i%3)*80,
          y: (stage.getHeight() / 2)-40+(i%2)*80,
          radius: 40,
          fillRadialGradientStartPoint: 0,
          fillRadialGradientStartRadius: 0,
          fillRadialGradientEndPoint: 0,
          fillRadialGradientEndRadius: 70,
          fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0, "rgb(225,17,17)", 1, "rgb(113,0,0)"],
          shadowColor: 'black',
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowOffset: 10,
          shadowOpacity: 0.5,
          opacity: 0.9,
          draggable: true,
          id: 'bubble'+i
        });

        bubble.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
          this.setScale(1.2);
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer'; <!-- zmiana kursora na lapke -->
          layer.draw();
        });
        bubble.on('dragmove', function() {
          <!-- miejsce na metode kolizji -->

          collide(this.getId(), this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getRadius()*1.2);

        });     
        bubble.on('mouseout touchend', function() {
          this.setScale(1);
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default'; <!-- zmiana kursora na domyslny -->
          layer.draw();
        });

        bubbleTab[i] = bubble;
        layer.add(bubble);
      }

      stage.add(layer);

      var transparentBtn =  document.getElementById("transparentBtn"),
          tween = TweenLite.to(group, 1, {setX:500, setY:0, onUpdate:layer.draw, onUpdateScope:layer, paused:true});

          transparentBtn.onclick = function() {
          tween.restart();
        }
    </script>
```

EDIT:

Ok I think about it and I have idea how do this without new event. I just call collision function always when any bubble collide with the bubble moved by me. It's working but I worry about performance. If you have any ideas ;) please tell me about it.

Below is the line of code that i added to every call method `setX()` of `setY()` in `function collide()`

```
collide(bubbleTab[i].getId(), bubbleTab[i].getX(), bubbleTab[i].getY(), bubbleTab[i].getRadius());
```

Comment: With only 6 bubbles, a loop won't be a performance hit. But if the number of bubble grows by orders of magnitude, that is when you should start worrying about it

Comment: Yeah i know, that is only example but i wish had 20 maybe 50 bubbles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here is a possible algorithm that you can try to implement!
Divide your stage (`Kinetic.Layer`) into a number of overlapping `Kinetic.Groups` (rectangular/square regions). The overlap should be slightly greater than max. possible radius of your bubbles, i.e. `r' > 1.2*radius`.

Now for each circle with center x,y add it to group that covers that region x,y.
During your collision detection now you'll only have to check through circles which are within this group(s) and they can be retrieved using `.getChildren()` method. This can be immensely helpful for larger simulation space containing a large number of circles.

And the same logic can be applied to all the circles that collide with the one that you are moving, to find out further collisions. Note that you'll have to add/remove circles from groups when they cross the boundaries.

This of course assumes that your bubbles are well distributed or else, your worst case will be same as your current implementation.

Comment: Nice idea :)! Thanks i will try implement this.